# How can i hide ReplyKeyboardMarkup in c#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want when user presses the keyboard markup button then hide that, create keyboard with this code:

```
Rkm_YesNo.Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][]
{
    new KeyboardButton[]
    {
        new KeyboardButton("\U0000274C" + " " + "خیر"),
        new KeyboardButton("\U00002705" + " " + "بلی")
    }
};
```

and send that with this code:

```
await
Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatid, "در حال بررسی لطفا صبور باشید",false,false,0,rkm);
```

How can I hide that keyboard? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set `OneTimeKeyboard=true`.

Comment: thanks my friend too pay attention my problem,where is set OnTimeKeyboard?

Comment: its in your rkm object. there is a bool type just set it true.